# Flutter: Realtime database appends list when listens changes

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using flutter and firebase realtime database.I'm trying to read data from a specific node.I'm saving the data that I am collecting in the Orderlist class and then I return a Future List of Ordelist.This Future function I am trying to use on another widget.I want to display on screen every time data is updated.

```
Future<List<Orderlist>> order() async{
  String business =await businessname();
  List table = await tables();
  
  List<Orderlist> list = [];
  table.forEach((element) async{
   
    String payment_method = '';
    String payment_state ='';
    var snapshot =  ref.child(business).child(element.toString()).onValue.listen((event) {
      event.snapshot.children.forEach((method) {
      
      if(method.key=='payment_method') payment_method=method.value.toString();
      if(method.key=='payment_state') payment_state = method.value.toString();
      
      
    });
    final order = Orderlist(payment_method: payment_method,payment_state: payment_state);
    
    list.add(order);
    });
    
  });
  
  return list;
}
```

The problem is that at first place the data are loaded on screen but when I am trying to update the data for some reason the list is appended whereas I just want to replace the previous data with the updated data.To be more specific if I want to listen to 2 nodes to be updated I will have a list with 2 Orderlist items.But the problem is when I update one of them the list is expanded to 3 Orderlist items.
Here is the widget where I am trying to use the Future function
[first data loaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynyK1.png) [Updated da](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPo8N.png)

```
class TempSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const TempSettings({super.key});

  @override
  State<TempSettings> createState() => _TempSettingsState();
}

class _TempSettingsState extends State<TempSettings> {
  String? business;
  List<Orderlist> list=[];
    final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
     
      g();
    
    
    super.initState();
  }
    void g() async{
      
      list = await DatabaseManager(user_uid: user!.uid).order();[![[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2NQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn2NQ.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ4M1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJ4M1.png)
      
    }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: list.map((e) => ListTile(title: Text(e.payment_method!),)).toList(),);
  }
}
```

Comment: is that the full code? because I dont see a set state call, so how exactly do you get flutter to rerender your screen?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @seven_seas no this is not the full code.This is the function which returns the list and the widget where I am using the function.I can't use set staste as function returns Future

Answer (score 1):

When you listen to data in Firebase with `onValue`, the `event` you get contains a snapshot of all data. Even when only one child node was added/changed/removed,  the snapshot will contain all data. So when you add the data from the snapshot to `list`, you are initially adding all child nodes once - but then on an update, you're adding most of them again.

The easiest way to fix this is to empty the list every time `onValue` fires an event by calling `list.clear()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried that too. The problem with this solution is that if I clear the list every time onValue fires I will get only one item instead of the 2 or more I want. I want to listen to some of the nodes.